# JPA Bidirectional OneToMany and ManyToOne?

Tags: oracle, jpa, oracle11g, one-to-many

I'm using Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 2.

I created two tables `A` and `B` using SQL developer.

Table `A` has a `FK` to table `B`. Using the Entities from Tables function, I created two JPA files from it.

`A` has `@ManyToOne` annotation on `FK`.

And also `B` has `@OneToMany` annotation to `A`. I don't want this.

Can I remove this `@OneToMany` annotation automatically?

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FIELD_B")
    private B b;
    ...
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
    private List<A> assetList;
    ...
}
```

I don't need @OneToMany mapping.

Comment: Can you show us the code? If you want to convert a bidirectional into a unidirectional relationship you probably have to modify it apart from removing one of them?

Comment: @GonzaloGarciaLasurtegui I added the code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it. Then only As know of their B, And a B doesnt know any A.
If you remove the  `@OneToMany` mapping you have to remove the referenced `List<A> assetList`, too.

Comment: I have to remove it manually? Can it make only unidirectional relationship automatically?

Comment: Yes. No i dont think so, a FK on a table will result in a bidirectional relationship always i think.